# Computational Complexity of an 'equivalent' 3SAT instance problem

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Given a random $3SAT$ instance $(S_0)$ with $C_0$ clauses, $I_0$ variables.

**Objective:** For any given value $C_1$ ($C_1<C_0$), create an 'equivalent' $3SAT$ instance $(S_1)$ with $I_0$ variables, $C_1$ clauses such that:
For any set of values for variables $I_0$, $S_0$ is satisfiable iff $S_1$ is satisfiable.

What is the computational complexity of this problem? It doesn't seem to be $NPComplete$ since there is no obvious way to verify the equivalence of two instances $S_0$ and $S_1$. Or I am missing something? Any refernces please?

Comment: Since the objective does not seem to depend on $C_1$ in any way, what's preventing you from picking $S_1 = S_0$? Also the problem cannot possibly be $\mathsf{NP}$-complete since it is not a decision problem.

Comment: I think I might not have made it very clear. When we are given $C_1$ as a target as part of the problem statement how can we assume $S_1=S_0$. The whole point is to minimize the 3SAT instance? We can also translate it into a decision problem by stating "Is there an equivalent 3SAT instance for a given value $C_1$ so that shouldn't be a problem. I am curious about the complexity of both: 1. Finding the equivalent 3SAT 2. The decision version of the form "Is there an.."

Comment: You never stated that the sought equivalent 3SAT instance must have $C_1$ clauses.

Comment: a mistake, making an edit. apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your problem can be solved in polynomial time. Then you can obtain an algorithm that solves 3SAT as follows.

Given an instance $\phi$ of 3SAT with $n \ge 3$ variables and $m \ge 9$ clauses, invoke a polynomial-time algorithm for your problem with $C_1=8$.

If your algorithm answers with a formula $\phi'$, then you can test at most $2^{24}$ instantiations of the (at most) $24$ variables involved in the $8$ clauses of $\phi'$ to decide whether $\phi$ is satisfiable.

If your algorithm determines that no such formula $\phi'$ exists, then $\phi$ is necessarily satisfiable since you can  always build a non-satisfiable 3SAT formula if you are allowed to use at least $3$ variables and $8$ clauses.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the minimum equivalent problem instance might have a size $C_1>8$. How does that say anything about satisfiablility or unsatisfiability of the original  problem? I am very confused.

Comment: If the minimum equivalent instance has more than 8 clauses then the original 3-SAT instance must be satisfiable.

Comment: I understood that assertion but I could not see the reasoning how hence the confusion. Moreover, I was searching for some equivalent problem and I stumbled on the MIN-EQ-DNF problem. That belongs to the second level in the Polynomial Hierarchy. Our problem is similar but has 2 differences: 1. Each clause is in CNF 2. Each clause has a fixed/exact size of 3 unlike the MIN-EQ-DNF problem. I was wondering if they are related?  Here is the link: https://theory.epfl.ch/courses/complexity/Lecture6.pdf